# listing linux file /etc/fstab in latex document

Tags: listings

In some document I have an `/etc/fstab` linux file listing with following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
/dev/mmcblk0p3 /mnt/data vfat noexec,rw,noatime,user,umask=000 0 2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I've attached screenshot of output. This output is somehow ugly to me, is there any `lstlisting`'s langauge support for linux system files?

[image]

Comment: @clemens, your hint has done the job! How do I advance your comment into answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout has nothing to do with the kind of file you're loading but depends on `listings`' options.

Try

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible]
```

Or probably rather as global options in the preamble:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
```

`listings` has quite a number of options for customizing the layout and appearance of the listings, have a look at [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).